# Is it possible to charge INITAMT during recurring payment profile using Credit cards?

Tags: paypal, credit-card, recurring-billing

Greetings to all.

Could you please help me with the Recurring payment profile thing. Is it possible to charge INITAMT to customer while creating recurring payment profile using credit cards ?

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

You can search the key words "INITAMT" in the link above for the details. It is an initial non-recurring payment amount due immediately upon profile creation.